# Type casting in c++

Tags: c++

In c++ can we cast an object to an integer ?

Clarifying my question - Suppose I have created an interface to handle file management task like create file, open file, read, write and I want to have one unique handle for every instance of a file. To achieve this can I create a file handle for each instance of the file interface by just type casting that instance to integer ?

To all - I hope now i am clear.

Comment: What do you mean by 'object'? There is no such built-in type in C++. Please provide an example what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: Please make you question clearer and provide more detail. A code example of what you are trying to do would probably be a good idea.

Comment: IMHO the question is clear, plus the comment of Kerido doesn't really make sense to me ....

Comment: Yes you can and believe me you ll regret it if you don't do it VERY VERY VERY carefully.

Comment: @RageZ: Kerido may be thinking of C# `object`, which is a built-in, and maybe OP is referring to it. I think so, too.

Comment: "Object" is a term which is defined in the ISO C++ standard. "Integer" could be taken as either `int` or one of the integral types, but that's not a big ambiguity. Still, I have to wonder like KennyTM what the motivation for this question was.

Comment: Clarifying my question - Suppose i have created an interface that do all the file management thing like file create, open, read, write and i want to have a unique handle of every instance of a file so for this can i create a file handle from every instance of the file interface by just type casting that instance to integer ?

Comment: To all - I hope now i am clear.

Comment: @khushi: edit your question please.

Comment: You say, "suppose I have to create an interface". If so, then it sounds like you should design the interface such that the file handle is a pointer type (like FILE*) rather than an integer type (like file descriptors). If there's a particular integer type pre-defined that you must use (`int`, say, or `short`), then you might need to use some form of lookup (perhaps a map or an array) between integers and pointers, to account for the possibility that pointers are bigger than that integer type.

Answer (score 5):

Not all objects. Every object in C++ has a type.  That type of an object defines whether a cast to `int` exists, and if so, what algorithm is used.

Answer (score 3):

If you have an object and want to cast it to `int` then you need to explicitly provide `operator int` for that class.

Answer (score 1):

```
class File
{
 public:
  ...
  ...
  operator int() { return int(this); }
  ...
}
```

Then

```
File myFile;
int myFileHandle = myFile;
```

Comment: `int` is not guaranteed to be as big as a pointer. Most 64-bit systems have 64-bit pointers and 32-bit ints so two different pointers can alias to the same int. You're better off using pointers as ID's and avoiding int entirely.

Comment: @Potatoswatter - Yes, you are right. Can u elaborate on how to use the pointer as Id's?

Comment: @khushi: what do you need an id to do? `void*` supports casting back to the original pointer type and testing for equality.

Answer (score 0):

Edit: Since you are mapping files to a unique handle, you can use a `std::vector<std::string>` or a `vector<shared_ptr<fstream> >` or a `vector<FILE*>`.

On a POSIX-compliant system there is also `fileno` to convert a `FILE*` into its file descriptor which is an `int`.

---

To get the hash: Use the `hash_value` function from boost.

To convert any value to integer lexically: Use the `lexical_cast<int>` function from boost

To cast the value to integer: Just use `(int)value`.

For the above to work, the class you're going to convert needs to implement some special member functions e.g. `operator<<` and `operator int`.

To convert an object into an arbitrary unique integer, use `(int)&value`.

To get a random integer, use `rand()`.

Answer (score 0):

I would rather convert to a `long` type. This is safer when a pointer value is converted to an integral type on an x64 machine. You can just use `reinterpret_cast<long>(myInterfacePointer)` in that case.

Comment: Also, casting pointers to int is a bad idea which is treading water.

Comment: You assume LP64, which is dangerous since Windows on both x64 and IA64 uses LLP64, and a `long` is 32 bit. asveikau is right, you should use uintptr_t, or if it's not available fake it up in a portability header.

Answer (score 0):

you can, but it depend on the sizeof(YourObject) compared to sizeof(int), by casting any object to int you will access the first 4 bytes part of your object (assuming sizeof(int) == 4), if your object is smaller than sizeof(int) somewhere you will get access violation or crash. to cast :

`

```
 MyObject object;
 int castedObject = *((int*)&object);
```

`

to cast without pointer intermediate, you must provide typecast operator inside MyObject class. or you can declare global static function of `int& operator=(const MyObject& object){...}`

Comment: That makes little sense and is unlikely to work, much less to guarantee any particular behavior at all.

Comment: well, before the question was edited, its unclear what he wanted, i just describe how to force cast any object to int regardless its effects

Comment: 1. sizeof(int)==4 is a poor assumption. 2. If object is smaller than int, crash is unlikely, you will probably get junk data. 3. If object is larger than int, which bytes are the first is platform-dependent. 4. Casting through a pointer is inadvisable for any task. 5. You cannot define an operator= outside a class, and hence cannot define for builtin type. 6. If you could, how would you construct the `int` in order to return an `int&`?

Comment: uray's point is valid, i.e. you can directly cast the first sizeof(int) bytes of an object's in-memory representation to an int. It's unlikely that this is ever what you want, still it does answer the OP's question. Whether or not sizeof(int) is 4 is immaterial to the answer.

Comment: @Roel: it's not immaterial because it determines the behavior of the program!

Comment: The program will behave differently depending on sizeof(int), but there was nothing in the question about what the behavior should be. My remark was in relation to your '1. sizeof(int) == 4 is a poor assumption' - what assumption is made about the size of int doesn't matter, it can be 4 or 8 or whatever, and still the fundamental answer is the same, namely that you can cast the first x bytes to an object to an integer, period. Whether or not that cast makes any sense is a whole different matter. All your points go into whether or not it *should* be done, which is irrelevant to the question.

Answer (score 0):

Why not just get the file descriptor/handle/whatever ID from the operating system and use that? Most systems have some kind of concept like that.

Consider using `void *` instead of `int` for the handles if you really want them to be pointers. Then casting a pointer-to-object to a handle is easy, and you can still hide the implementation away.

Comment: yes, u r right but i have limitation on this part that i have to generate this file handle.

Comment: generate UUID for each instance maybe?

Comment: @khushi: what limitations do you have on the file handle? What do you need that an `int` can do but a `void*` can't?

Answer (score 0):

In response to @potatoswatter's comment to my first response.

I don't like the idea of casting objects. I would rather use a hashing function that produces an integer hash, say based on the filename or read/write flags. Now, I have to post another answer

```
class File
{
 public:
  ...
  ...
  operator int();
  ...
 private:
  char fileName[];
  int flags;
};
```

The integer conversion operator is now a hashing function:

```
File::operator int()
{
 int hash = 0;
 int c;
 char *str = fileName;

 while (c = *str++)
    hash += c;

 hash += flags;

 return hash;
}
```

I know the hash function is lousy. But you can avoid casts that are lousier and come up with your own hashing function that suits your needs better.

Comment: In this case, IMO you'd be much better off using a named function (`getHash()`). Casting classes to primitives probably only makes sense when the class emulates a primitive to begin with.